# Field conversion

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access form that goes to a back end table. Users enter a time frame and there is a corresponding conversion I want to tell if they are making production. I have created a field to house this conversion.

Is there a way in Access if users enter a time function it will then complete the other field for the conversion? I am not sure how.

I have a second table that has all of the values and the conversions.[This is backend conversion table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a0DV.png). Is there a way to just reference if this value is entered on to table place this value from other table in this field? Then I could build my production queries.

Answer (score 0):

A time difference can be found with *DateDiff*:

```
Minutes = DateDiff("n", StartTime, EndTime)
```

Your conversion can then be calculated by this formula:

```
Conversion = -Int(-(Minutes - 2) / 60 * 10) / 10
```

For example: 94 minutes -> 1.6

Comment: See that is my issue as they enter column a which is text and minutes I need to get the corresponding column B to show so I can then convert. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Not really. What is entered, and what should the output be? And where?